# Prestashop : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token chrome only

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, prestashop

I'm receiving `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token=` error in chrome browser only and the error pointing near by my function

```
function updateSalesQty(id_sale,id_product,id_customer,sign=0,qty=0)
    {
```

Error pointing here

```
$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'index.php?controller=AdminCarts&token=fc9ff5f59559a3d4137b247a768bf320',
                data : {
                    ajax: '1',
                    token: 'fc9ff5f59559a3d4137b247a768bf320',
                    tab: 'AdminCarts',
                    action: 'updateSaleQty',
                    id_sale: id_sale,   
                    id_product: id_product,     
                    id_customer: id_customer,               
                    sign:sign,  
                    qty:qty,                                
                },
                success : function(res)
                {
                  $('#customer_sale tbody').html(res);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: And what is your question now? A syntax error means that your syntax is incorrect, so the `=` is not allowed there. You have to edit your code and fix the error.

Comment: I would be surprised if this works in Firefox. I also assume you haven't tested in IE?

Comment: @JanDvorak FF supports default parameters as well as some other ES6 features. In fact much better then Chrome. http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/

Comment: @dfsq I knew about ES6 support in Firefox, but not about ES6 support for default arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updateSalesQty(id_sale,id_product,id_customer,sign=0,qty=0)
```

So far, [only firefox supports default arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters) in JS.
You'd have to set the defaults inside of the function, for example like

```
sign = sign || 0;
```

or

```
qty = (typeof qty !== 'undefined') ? qty : 0;
```